# Error in Fitting a curve using curve_fit in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

**I'm trying to fit the next function into some data using the Scipy Curve_fit function:**

```
def sinugauss(x, A, B, C):
    exponente = A*(np.sin(x-B))**2
    return np.array([C/(np.exp(exponente))])
```

**I have a data set of 33 points but I keep getting this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "D:Es_periodico_o_no.py", line 35, in <module>\
    res, cov = curve_fit(sinugauss,datos['x'],datos['y'])\
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 789, in curve_fit\
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)\
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 414, in leastsq
    raise TypeError(f"Improper input: func input vector length N={n} must"\
TypeError: Improper input: func input vector length N=3 must not exceed func output vector length M=1
```

**This is the full code:**

```
def sinugauss(x, Ventas, Inicio, Desv):
    exponente = Desv*(np.sin(x-Inicio))**2
    return np.array([Ventas/(np.exp(exponente))])

for index, row in real_df.iterrows():
    datos_y = np.array([row]).transpose()
    datos_x = np.array([range(len(datos_y))]).transpose()
    datos = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([datos_x,datos_y]),columns=['x','y'])
    res, cov = curve_fit(sinugauss,datos['x'],datos['y'])
    print(res)
    print(cov)
```

The error raises since the first iteration, all the rows has 33 not nan points. There may be zeros

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `sinugauss`, change the return statement to:

```
    return C/np.exp(exponente)
```

When you write `np.array([C/(np.exp(exponente))])`, you are wrapping the expression `C/np.exp(exponente)`, which might be an array with shape, say, `(3,)`, in a 2-d array with shape `(1, 3)`.  That is not the shape that `curve_fit` expects from your function.

Comment: I don't understand how that is related with the message " must not exceed func output vector length M=1". What would be the output vector length in your two situations?